# symfony shell-command will get executed as www-data user and crash ssl request

Tags: shell, symfony, permissions, command

As I try to execute a shell command which opens up an ssl-session and just touch a file, it won't work from inside a symfony command.
Calling the script by symfony web frontend will end up with an

> host key verification failed.

which is correct as the user is now www-data and not my personal user.

To fix it, I should have a key for the www-data user, but as this is no switchable user, how can I get this done?

Comment: This error does not relate to the user key (but doesn't mean there's no problem there), but the remote server: "**host key** verification failed". This can happen if the server has changed hostname or host key or in a MitM attack scenario. If you are sure the server is legitimate, you can remove the host from `~www-data/.ssh/known_hosts`. To disable it you can append `-o StrictHostChecking=no` to the ssh command, but to edit the file you'll need root privileges.

Comment: But why is it, that I can call it by terminal if I am logged in with my normal ssh user? It just won't work by www-data.

Comment: Host checking is usually an interactive process, at least the first time. I'm guessing that since there is no shell or user, the check can't complete.